# incompatible types:java.util.date

Tags: java, kotlin

I get a compile error in the form:

```
incompatible types:java.util.date cannot to be converted to java.sql.Date
```

```
Date date=null;
date=new SimpleDateFormat("d MM y").parse((String)getSutunlar().get(index).getProduct_date());
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `SimpleDateFormat` returns `java.util.date` and you are trying to assign the result in the `date` variable of instance type `java.sql.Date`. You should have a look at the imports (at the top of your .java file), and try replacing `java.sql.Date` with `java.util.date`.